# Strip Base64 strings from long text

Tags: php, regex

I really wonder if I'm really the first one asking this question or am I so blind to finde some about this...

I have a longer text and I want to strip base64 encoded strings of it

> I am a text and have some lines with some content
>
> There are more than one line but sometimes I have
>
> aSBhbSBhIG5vcm1hbCB0ZXh0IHRoYXQgd2FzIGNvZ
>
> GVkIGluIGJhc2UgNjQgYW5kIG5vdyBpIHdhcyB0cmFu
>
> c2xhdGVkIGJhY2sgdG8gYmxhbmsgdGV4dGZvcm1hd
>
> C4gaSB0aGFuayB5b3UgZm9yIHBheWluZyBhdHRlbnRp
>
> b24uIGJ5ZQ==
>
> and this is what I want to strip / extract by using php

As you can see there is base64 encoded data in the text and I want to extract/strip these lines.

I allready tried a lot of regex samples from SO something like

```
$regex = '@^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$@m';
preg_match($regex, $content, $output_array );
```

but this not solved anything...

What I need is a regex that only selects the base strings...

Is this even possible ? I mean is base64 selectable by regex ? **I guess** :)

**EDIT: String-Source is the content of an email**

**EDIT2: Guess the best syntax for this case your be so track strings that has more than one uppdercased character and can have numbers and has no whitespaces. But regex is not my daily bread :D**

Comment: Do you have base64 strings occurring i through text?

Comment: sorry, i dont understand ?!?!?!

Comment: The point is, the customer will copy the whole content of the mail because hes not very familier with distinguishing strings. so i told him to copy the whole content. problem non base64 strings mess up the output. so i have to get rid of them before :)

Answer (score 2):

**First of all:** You can not reliably do this!

**Why?**

Simple, the point why base64 is so great in some cases is, that is encodes all the data with "standard" characters. Those that are used in normal texts, sentences, and yes, even words.

**Background**

Is "Hello" a base64-encoded string? Well, yes, in the meaning of it is "valid base64 encoded". It probably returns a lot of jibberish, but it is a base64-ok string.

Therefore, you can only decide on a length after which you consider characters connected without any space to be base64 encoded. Of course in languages such as german you may have quite some trouble here, as there a compound nouns, such as "Bäckerfachverkäuferinnenhosenherstellungsautomatenzuliefererdienst" or such (just made that up).

**Workaround**

So on the length you have to decide yourself, an then you can go with this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\+\/\=]{20,}
```

Also see the example here: https://regex101.com/r/uK5gM1/1

I considered "20" to be the minimum length for "base64 encoded stuff" here, but as said, it is up to you. Also, as a small side note, the `=` is not really encoded content but fill bytes, but I still added it to the regex.

*Edit:* Gnah.. you can even see in my example that I did not catch the last line :) When changing the number to 12 it works fine here, but there may be words with more than 12 characters ... so - as said, not really reliably possible in this manner.

Comment: "Hello" cannot be a Base64 string cause it misses the `=` padding. Even than "Hello=" cannot give a valid UTF8 result :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You are right! However, PHP is weird and you can actually decode it: https://eval.in/505957 but not with the padding. Weird, huh?

Comment: Nice explanation. I see the point... so there is no way to tell the regex that new line could be still the same word ?

Comment: In general not, but you may spot a pattern checking several emails.  https://regex101.com/r/dE5vF9/1 works for the given example.

Comment: Im still working on it because actualy the basecode is long or has numbers in it. So im testing the regex like (has small AND big letters AND can have Numbers) I would like to create a regex like (string has at least 2 uppercased chars) because no language has camelwritestyle :D

Answer (score 1):

For the snippet in the example `/^\w{53}$/gm` does the job. If you can rely on length of course.

**EDIT:**

Considering circumstances and updates, I would go with `/\n([\w=\n]{50,})\n/gs` but without metadata it may be tricky to guess mime-type of the decoded stuff, and almost impossible to restore filenames etc.

Comment: actually i dont know the length. it could be longer or shorter.. its a email content

Comment: Well, it is quite another question then =) In email your base64 encoded strings are not randomly spread over the text. In email you have boundaries and  `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`

Comment: actually I agree with that. BUT, a customer of my company moved some emails from one programm to an other one with a tool. Dont know anything about that tool. So since he did this, all the mails have plain base64 content and he allready deleted all original mails... round about 1k mails. and he still needs the data. so I set him a page where he can c&p the content with every crap in there and get out the encoded stuff. So the question actually is right. But yes, you are also right :)